# How to use JQuery Contains with id selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to use the jQuery contains selector only for a table with a unique id.
I tried it like this but doesnt work.

```
var x = "tree";
$( "#TableID.tr:contains('" + x + "')").css( "background-color", "red" );
```

The code should change the backgroundcolor of every row which contains x in the tr tag in a table with the id TableID.

Can anyone help me with the correct syntax?

Comment: show us your table code

Comment: Table and tr share parent child relationship, so the selector should be something like

$('#TableID tr:contains('+ x +')')

Comment: `$( "#TableID tr:contains('" + x + "')").css( "background-color", "red" );`

Comment: Arun P Jhonys answer was the solution. Thank you, I did a "." where i shouldnt do one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use descendant selector for the table and the tr element

```
$( "#TableID tr:contains('" + x + "')").css( "background-color", "red" );
```

Your code looks for a table with id `TableID` with class `tr` and contains the given text some where within it

Answer (score 2):

You need to separte the `.tr` form the table id and remove the dot as it is not a class element.

```
$( "#TableID tr:contains('" + x + "')").css( "background-color", "red" );
```

[**Living demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/TJ3ET/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$( "tr:contains('" + x + "')").css( "background-color", "red" );
```

Demo link http://jsfiddle.net/dhana36/YT3CD/2/